# Component not found: Microsoft-Windows-Security-SPP-UX, reported by System File Checker

Tags: windows-7, system-file

The initial problem is, suddenly my Windows 7 64-bit Ultimate is reported not genuine. However, it is purchased from Microsoft few years ago. The error code is **0xC8000247**. After reading some Microsoft forum, it is suggested that the system may be corrupted, and they suggest me to use System File Checker ( sfc ) multiple times.

After I run `sfc /scannow` in elevated Command Prompt (the logged in user is Administrator) twice, a `CBS.log` is generated. By using the following command:

```
C:\Users\MyUserName>findstr /c:"[SR]" %windir%\Logs\CBS\CBS.log >"%userprofil
e%\Desktop\sfcdetails.txt"
```

Then a `sfcdetails.txt` is generated on my desktop. Here is the key lines:

> 2013-08-25 00:27:05, Error                 CSI    0000006b (F) [SR]
>   Component not found: Microsoft-Windows-Security-SPP-UX, Version =
>   6.1.7600.16385, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS,
>
> PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName
>   neutral, PublicKey neutral[gle=0x80004005] 2013-08-25 00:27:05, Error 
>   CSI    0000006d (F) [SR] Component not found:
>   Microsoft-Windows-Security-SPP-UX, Version = 6.1.7600.16385, pA =
>   PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_IA32_ON_WIN64 (10), Culture neutral,
>   VersionScope = 1
>
> nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral,
>   TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral[gle=0x80004005] 2013-09-01
>   09:05:02, Error                 CSI    00000031 (F) [SR] Component not
>   found: Microsoft-Windows-Security-SPP-Client, Version =
>   6.1.7600.16385, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS,
>
> PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName
>   neutral, PublicKey neutral[gle=0x80004005] 2013-09-01 09:05:14, Error 
>   CSI    00000033 (F) [SR] Component not found:
>   Microsoft-Windows-Security-SPP-Client, Version = 6.1.7600.16385, pA =
>   PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL (0), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1
>   nonSxS,
>
> PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName
>   neutral, PublicKey neutral[gle=0x80004005]

Also, the forum suggests that I run the following commands in a batch file, in Clean Boot mode:

```
net stop wuauserv 
ren %windir%\SoftwareDistribution\WuRedir WRold
ren %windir%\SoftwareDistribution\DataStore DSold
ren %windir%\SoftwareDistribution\Download Dold
ren %windir%\SoftwareDistribution\SelfUpdate SUold
net start wuauserv
```

After rebooting to Normal Mode, the problem persists. Windows Update still fails & it is told my Windows is not genuine.

Also, they suggest me to execute `REGSVR32 WINTRUST.DLL` and the response is succeeded. Still fail.

What should I do next to fix these issues?

Comment: Your installation appears corrupt beyond the ability to repair it.

Comment: sigh, Microsoft.

Comment: Microsoft didn't cause your installation to become corrupt.  Critical system files are corrupt this is normally caused by a hdd that is about to fail.

Answer (score 0):

You need to repair [Windows 7 by doing an Inplace upgrade](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html).

- Insert a Windows 7 DVD into your drive (or mount an ISO)
- Run setup.exe from the DVD inside Windows
- select `Upgrade` and follow the setup.

Comment: Already tried. After loading for a while after click Upgrade. The upgrade said, "Installation has failed". Then I rollback.